# Why is cutoff parameter in igraph in r not applicable?

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I want to calculate closeness centrality on a disconnected graph. `closeness` function in igraph in r is not well-defined for disconnected graphs since the closeness of a vertex is defined as the inverse of the average distance to all other vertices, and so if there are two vertices that have no path between them, closeness measures of these vertices can not be computed properly. To somehow cure this issue, `estimate_closeness` function in igraph is suggested, it works for disconnected graphs by specifying `cutoff`parameter as being greater than zero.

However, when I try to run `V(network)$closeness <- estimate_closeness(network, mode = "all", cutoff > 0)`, it gives the following error:

`Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, vids) : object 'cutoff' not found`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you give us a [mcve], i.e. edit your code to define a small disconnected graph?

Comment: Your function call uses a variable called `cutoff`, and R is telling you that you haven't got a variable with that name.

Comment: The function `estimate_closeness` needs a number for `cutoff`.

Comment: from the documentation: cutoff = the maximum path length to consider when calculating the betweenness. If zero or negative then there is no such limit.

Comment: Instead of putting `cutoff > 0` in your function call,  try `cutoff = 10`